# ISO forbids declaration of "identifier" with no type.

Tags: c++, types, header, iso

Ok I know there are millions of variations of this particular problem, and I have tried (desperately) to go through them all and see if they apply, to no avail.

Currently I'm trying to declare a deque in a header file, and the damn thing wont let me due to the error mentioned. The same thing happens to me in a lot of my projects, and I think its just something basic I'm lacking in my knowledge of c++ class syntax.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include "Card.h"
#include "random.h"

using namespace std;

void            createloop();
int             get_option();
deque <Card>    make_new_deck();
deque <Card>    load_new_deck();

int main()
{
    createloop();
    return 0;
}
```

I havn't shown the rest of the file for clarities sake, and im pretty confident it isnt the problem. The error appears in Card.h:

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card
{
    public:
        Card();

        deque<string> param_name_deque;
        deque<double> param_value_deque;
        virtual ~Card();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // CARD_H
```

card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"


Card::Card()
{
    //ctor
}

Card::~Card()
{
    //dtor
}
```

To anyone who can help - thanks in advance! Ill be very happy when I understand whats wrong here!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include both std::deque and std::string in your header file `card.h`

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
```

Meanwhile,

```
deque<string> param_name_deque;
deque<double> param_value_deque;
```

should be

```
std::deque<std::string> param_name_deque;
std::deque<double> param_value_deque;
```

Comment: ahhhh forgot to write "using namespace std"! Totally forgot you had to identify your namespace in haeder files - staggeringly stupid of me.

Comment: @OwenMcConnell - not writing `using namespace std;` is correct. What you forgot is to qualify the names with `std::`. Don't get in the habit of blasting everything into the global namespace; there are good reasons for having these things in their own namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `namespace` in `card.h` when you declare the `param_name_deque` and `param_value_deque`:

```
std::deque<std::string> param_name_deque;
std::deque<double> param_value_deque;
```

and include the proper headers:

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
```

I would avoid [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c), it may seem convenient but it will eventually cause you problems.

Comment: Ok thanks - ill try to refrain from using namespace std from now on.